# Region selection is greyed out when attempting to create VM in Azure cloud

Tags: azure, azure-vm

[image: VM Creation Unavailable Region]

I have had the option select different region in the past. Suddenly I am not able to select different region to create a VM. It is fixed to Australia East. Whats wrong with my setting? Is there anything I can do to fix?

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue and what was happening was the custom image I had created was in the region that was selected.  If you select a generally available image, you should get the option of deploying the scale set anywhere.  If you need to use the custom image, try moving that image or copying it to the region you want to deploy the scale set to

Answer (score 0):

What type of Azure subscription are you using?  Maybe check the usage + quotas section of the subscription and make sure you have availability to deploy VMs in other regions.

Comment: My subscription is 'Microsoft Azure Sponsorship'. I checked in the 'Usage & Quotas' section, I have access to all regions and I have very little usage of the VMs.

Comment: Unless it's a limitation of the sponsorship program that you are on then I'm not sure.  Have you the ability to log a support ticket with Microsoft through the Azure portal?  Even if you don't log it as a technical ticket, the subscription support may be able to confirm if this is a limitation for you and why.